# Disease network

Tags: networking, cytoscape

I have a table with two columns: One column contains `Disease names` the other contains `Genes`. I want to create a graph of only `Disease nodes`, connecting two nodes if they have a common gene affecting them.

How can I do this in Cytoscape?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be desirable if you included whatever code you have tried thus far. Consider some of the guidelines in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) namely ["how do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a button (or import function) in Cytoscape that will perform this transformation automatically. You would need to perform this transformation prior to network import in order to construct the network model that you want. Or you could perform it in a number of steps in Cytoscape, following an algorithm like this:

1. Import disease-gene network
2. Identify sets of disease nodes adjacent to a given gene node (e.g., select each gene and then select first neighbors; or use Filters)
3. Connect nodes within each set as a clique (all connected to all) (e.g., right-click on selected set, Add > Edges Connecting Selected Nodes)
4. Delete gene nodes (and consequently all disease-gene connections) (e.g., select all nodes; or use Filters)

If you like R or Python, then you could leverage the [RCy3](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RCy3.html) or [py4cytoscape](https://github.com/cytoscape/py4cytoscape) packages to interact with Cytoscape while doing the transformation by script.